# T SQL Table Valued Function to Split varbinary(max) into 16byte GUIDs

Tags: t-sql, functions

I am trying to write a function which will split a varbinary(max) field into a table with 16 byte GUIDs, but am struggling. I haven't been able to find any examples or walkthroughs on how to do this using varbinaries - so any help appreciated. An example of the data in the varbinary field I am trying to split is:

```
0x09B57E7B1E19CD448698ECDA170B080F7C98FD411E5D264EB6D83AD6D4067C0D336E73299D2408438B625B09BED408D2D8E6C6DE4310194ABD90CF90F1558838731B2B740B508E44843FA98125ADF599669FC433BD4C074294C64E13D880A3ED78D25157C1E7A946B5B9C78E8DA0B5A8ECA73BB5CE59E6439586C445F25F2CDCA2B69483A7AE184A922DBC895C2EEB47910B88E915B7B94FB0EFC84568E2C83F0EF3168F62B6CB4EBA849486164F6DA7805C85383FBF694DB606904E0BA1364DC2DECDC1D00DED4BA28D0F1AA3DD9D1E1AA98697B914924995A26512C7EBD7C1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is easy if you have a numbers table. The following example is cut and pasted from Erland Sommarskog's site:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fixbinary_single(@str varbinary(MAX))
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN(SELECT listpos = n.Number,
              n = convert(int, substring(@str, 4 * (n.Number - 1) + 1, 4))
       FROM   Numbers n
       WHERE  n.Number <= datalength(@str) / 4 )
```

Comment: @Jim: you don't need to add the tally table to that db. You can add it to master or maybe a DBA database and just reference it with full name.

Comment: Thanks!  I used this technique to help me set and test for bit values in a large varbinary field.  Breaking it down into discrete chunks allowed me to do the manipulation with low overhead!

Answer (score 3):

A **recursive** approach to splitting the GUIDs.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.splitGUIDs(@guids varbinary(max))
returns table as return
with CTE(item, remainder) as (
select CAST(CAST(left(@guids, 16) as binary(16)) as uniqueidentifier), stuff(@guids, 1, 16, '')
where @guids > ''
union all
select CAST(CAST(left(remainder, 16) as binary(16)) as uniqueidentifier), stuff(remainder, 1, 16, '')
from cte
where remainder > ''
)
select item from cte
--option (maxrecursion 0);
GO
```

**NOTE** that I have put `option(maxrecursion 0)` into the function, but you need it in your outer query if your list of guids contains more than 100 entries, e.g.

```
SELECT item
  FROM dbo.splitGUIDS(@guids) x
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Compared to using a Tally/Number table

- good: doesn't depend on such a table
- bad: could be slower
- good: no inherent upper limit of items (Tally table size limits the number of items extracted using table method)
- bad: you have to remember to use OPTION MAXRECURSION for large lists, in the *caller* query

Comment: The recursion limit could be significantly relaxed if the algorithmen uses a binary tree. Then you can decode 2^n values with a depth of n.